# SSIS Source Format Implicit Conversion for Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

Does anyone know of a chart that shows which formats of dates are supported by the different datatypes in SSIS? For example, does `DT_DBTimestamp` support the format `1-Jan`. I tried looking but couldn't find anything.

The reason I ask is that I found that when I try to do a `Convert(datetime, '1-Jan')` it fails which I expected. However, when I pull this same value into SSIS into the `DT_DBTimestamp`, it will implicitly identify it as `1/1/2017` rather than redirect the row as a datatype conversion error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General Info

These are the default formats of datetimes datatypes (when converting from string)

```
DT_DBDATE
yyyy-mm-dd

DT_FILETIME
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:fff

DT_DBTIME
hh:mm:ss

DT_DBTIME2
hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]

DT_DBTIMESTAMP
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]

DT_DBTIMESTAMP2
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]

DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffff] [{+|-} hh:mm]
```

*Note: DT_DATE and DT_DBTIMESTAMP has the same [SET  method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.pipelinebuffer.setdatetime.aspx)*

*And i think that converting string to date is depending also on your current culture info*

More detailed information are found here

- [Integration Services Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SSIS TO SQL SERVER DATA TYPE TRANSLATIONS](https://devinknightsql.com/2010/12/22/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations/)

### Experiments :

After reading your comment i didn't find any related article to your question so i made the following experiments:

**SSIS Implicit datetime Conversion**

i created a SSIS package with a Dataflowtask. in this dataflowtask i created a Script Component (as a Source) and a Flat File Destination. The script has one output column `OutDate` of type `DT_DbTimeStamp` Inside the script i used the following code:

```
Private dtDate As Date = #01/01/2016#

Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()

    Output0Buffer.AddRow()


    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("D:\Result.txt", False)
        sw.WriteLine("CultureInfo;Date;Format;Accepted")
        sw.Close()
    End Using


    For Each ci As System.Globalization.CultureInfo In System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures)

        For Each strFormat As String In ci.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns

            Dim boolResult As Boolean = True
            Try


                Output0Buffer.OutDate = dtDate.ToString(strFormat)

                boolResult = True

            Catch ex As Exception

                boolResult = False



            End Try

            Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("D:\Result.txt", True)
                sw.WriteLine(ci.Name & ";" & dtDate.ToString(strFormat) & ";" & strFormat & ";" & boolResult.ToString)
                sw.Close()
            End Using

        Next



    Next



End Sub
```

First i am looping over all culture info and i am Getting all datetime formats related to it and looping over them. Then i am trying to convert the date `dtDate` declared to a formatted string and assign it to the Output column.

So if assigning string value with specified format to DT_DBTIMESTAMP output column is accepted that means the format is implicit converted

```
Output0Buffer.OutDate = dtDate.ToString(strFormat)
```

And Here is the Link of the Result File:

- [Result.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0f1kmbzgh78fkxw/Result.txt?dl=0)

**SQL Server datetime Implicit Conversion**

There are two datetime string formats that are interpreted correctly with with any language setting.

```
yyyyMMdd
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss    (ISO8601)
```

Also, you can repeat the same experiment But this time by creating an `SqlCommand` and executing it:

```
Dim sqlcmd as new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + dtdate.ToString(strFormat) + '")"

sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
```

That way you can if sqlcmd throws an exception it means that format cannot be converted.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did come across those references you listed, however I'm looking for what formats will be implicitly converted from string to DT_DBTIMESTAMP, not what the final format will be output by SSIS. As mentioned in the question, for example, how come CONVERT to Datetime fails for '1-Jan', but SSIS will implicitly convert it to datetime and output it as '2017-01-01 00:00:00'.