# Import date into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I am importing this `.csv` and I would like to import the column `Date` as a date, not as a string:

[image]

Which data type should I choose: `date` or `database date`?

[image]

After importing it, will SQL Server be able to recognize it as a date?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose `DT_DATE` or `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` Data Type, both works.

Follow my answer at [SSIS Source Format Implicit Conversion for Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035354/ssis-source-format-implicit-conversion-for-datetime/42038060#42038060) it is very useful to you to know if this date format can be readed as Date value or need to be converted via a script component or else...

And you can Read more about IntergrationServices Data Types in these articles:

- [Integration Services Data Types MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)
- [SSIS to SQL Server Data Type Translations](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1387/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations)