# Is there a better way to parse [Integer].[Integer] style dates in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I'm working on an SSIS ELT script that needs to parse dates from a TSV file that are stored in the format `[INTEGER].[INTEGER]` ([Excel integer dates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) followed by second since midnight, e.g., 42825.94097; or microseconds since midnight, e.g., 42831.1229166667). I've come up with the following approach:

1. Derived Column function to split the input into a date part and a time part
2. Derived Column function to append the parsed dates together, e.g.,

   ```
   DATEADD("day",StartTime_Date,DATEADD("second",StartTime_Time,(DT_DATE)"1/1/1900"))
   ```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without resorting to a Script Component?

Comment: I have difficulty understanding the format. Can you explain what e.g. date/time 42825.94097 represents?

Comment: @TheEsisia I updated the question

Comment: @rjzii just use a derived column with the following expression `(DT_DATE)(DT_R8)[dateColumn]` take a look at my answer update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The DT_DATE data type is implemented using an 8-byte floating-point number. Days are represented by whole number increments, starting with 30 December 1899, and midnight as time zero. Hour values are expressed as the absolute value of the fractional part of the number. However, a floating point value cannot represent all real values; therefore, there are limits on the range of dates that can be presented in DT_DATE." *[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types)*

From the description above you can see that **you can convert these values implicitly when mapping them to a `DT_DATE` Column after converting it to a 8-byte floating-point number `DT_R8`.**

Use a derived column transformation to convert this column to 8-byte floating-point number:

```
(DT_R8)[dateColumn]
```

Then map it to a `DT_DATE` column

Or cast it twice:

```
(DT_DATE)(DT_R8)[dateColumn]
```

**Experiments**

i created a SSIS package with one `DataFlow Task`

The DataFlow Task Contains a Script Component (as Source) that generate one output row (one column of type DT_R8) with the value `42825.94097`.

The Script Component is linked to a derived column that convert this column into `DT_DATE` using the following expression

```
(DT_DATE)[Column]
```

the output i get is as shown below

[image]

**Related answers**

I have many answers related with this question:

- [CAST vs ssis data flow implicit conversion difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635787/cast-vs-ssis-data-flow-implicit-conversion-difference/43643995#43643995)
- [SSIS Source Format Implicit Conversion for Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035354/ssis-source-format-implicit-conversion-for-datetime/42038060#42038060)
- [SSIS Error importing Excel Date (truncation error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654040/ssis-error-importing-excel-date-truncation-error/42680251#42680251)

Comment: Try converting using a derived column with this expression `(DT_DATE)[InColumn]` (i didn't try it).

Comment: What is the source type?

Comment: Try converting this value to float `(DT_R8)[InColumn]` then map it to a `DT_DATE` colunn. Because i think the source column is of type text

Comment: Your solution is good. But i think it is better to achieve it using implicit conversion.

Comment: @rjzii i rewrite my answer to look better. hope this helps

Comment: if these digits are not important you can trim then using `LEFT(...,11)` function. but i think that DT_DATE supports micro seconds