# Convert bigint to date in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to convert the number in BigInt format to the Date format in SSIS, can anyone please help me to get out of it.
I apply below code but it does not work for me

```
DATEADD("SECOND",CreatedAt / 1000,(DT_DBTIME)"1/1/1970")
```

Comment: why are you dividing by 1000 ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287850/is-there-a-better-way-to-parse-integer-integer-style-dates-in-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

You are having `DT_DBTIME`. Instead, you should be having `DT_DBDTIMESTAMP`. It is the one corresponding to Datetime

```sql
DATEADD("second",(DT_I8)createdAt/1000,(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1/1/1970")
```

> CreatedAt = 2000
> DATEADD("second",(DT_I8)createdAt,(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1/1/1970") => 1970-01-01 00:00:02