# How to convert Date Time format from 'YYYY-MM-DD' to 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM'

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, ssis

I have a .csv file source. I am importing that into ssis to do some changes manipulation to generate a .csv file of special format. Date is coming from .Csv file.

I am in need to convert the date format which is in yyyy-mm-dd to 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM' for certain date column. For example: Report entry column has date 2017-03-27 needs to be converted to 03/27/2017 HH:MM:SS AM. How do i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FORMAT as below

```
    select format(getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
Select convert(datetime,'your date',103)
```

Comment: Date is coming from the .csv file and I've to change the format in the package, where the output should look like MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM.

Comment: Then you can use convert with option 103

Answer (score 2):

Use a script component.  Assuming the date column is a string:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.date = Convert.ToDateTime(Row.date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: I tried it. There is a error.The binary code for the script is not found.

Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it 

builds successfully

Comment: Open the script and build it, look at the errors window for what the errors are.  You may have to include the column in the script editor, update the column name, do different handling based on the data type.

Answer (score 1):

If the Date column is a string you can use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method in a script component. *(assuming that `outDate` is the output column and `inDate` is the input column)*

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;


CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.outDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.inDate,"yyyy-MM-dd",provider).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

for more info on this method you can refer to this links:

- [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)
- [C# DateTime.Parse](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse)

Also take a look a my answer in the following link, it is very helpful:

- [SSIS Source Format Implicit Conversion for Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035354/ssis-source-format-implicit-conversion-for-datetime/42038060#42038060)