# SSIS Derived Column Date Formats

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a large data file that I am running through SSIS. Very simple `XML source` into a `SQL database`. I seldom use SSIS so I am far from an expert.

I have some records that I push into an error table because the dates are incorrect.

What I want to say is, if the date is not in a date format, then update this `date` to `NULL`.

I don't know if `Derived Column` is the way to go, but it appears it should be given examples I have been reading online.

I want to fix this issue in the SSIS stage, not in SQL after the data has been loaded in to the error tables.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a `script component` instead of using a `derived column` to achieve this because `Scripts` contains more options to manipulate dates.

If you want to check for specific dates formats you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method or you use [DateTime.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to try parsing date based on CultureInfo Date Formats.

First you have to add a `Script component`, mark the date column as input, create a new output column of type `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`

**I will give two examples:**
*Assuming that the input Column name is `inDate` and the output column is `outDate`*

*DateTime.TryParseExact()*

```
Dim strFormats() As String = {"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)



    If Not Row.inDate_IsNull AndAlso
                 Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.inDate) Then


        Dim dtTemp As DateTime

        If DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.inDate, strFormats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtTemp) Then

            Row.outDate = dtTemp

        Else

            Row.outDate_IsNull = True

        End If



    End If
End Sub
```

*DateTime.TryParse()*

```
 Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)



    If Not Row.inDate_IsNull AndAlso
                 Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.inDate) Then


        Dim dtTemp As DateTime

        If DateTime.TryParse(Row.inDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtTemp) Then

            Row.outDate = dtTemp

        Else

            Row.outDate_IsNull = True

        End If



    End If
End Sub
```

you can read more about Datetime conversion using SSIS script component in this posts:

- [SSIS Source Format Implicit Conversion for Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035354/ssis-source-format-implicit-conversion-for-datetime/42038060#42038060)
- [SSIS convert string date with various formats to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441398/ssis-convert-string-date-with-various-formats-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Error Output of the component which fails to convert from text to date.

It is usually either a `Data Conversion`, or a `Derived Column` component. 
In case you are already receiving the column in date format from the source - it is your `XML Source` component.

- 1a. Double-click on yout `Data Conversion` or `Derived Column` component, and go to `Configure Error Output`.
- 1b. Double-click on your `XML Source`, go to the `Error Output`.
- 2. For your date column change the default `Error` and `Truncation` options to **Ignore Failure**.

The values which failed to convert will now contain NULLs instead.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141679(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

SSIS expressions are limited in date and error handling.  I would suggest, instead, to use a script component.

- Under input columns, select the column that you want to work with.  In the example below, my column is called "date"
- Add the following to the script:

  ```
  using System.Globalization;
  public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
  {
      CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
      DateTime dateResult;
      if (!DateTime.TryParse(Row.date, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateResult))
      {
          Row.date = null;
      }
  }
  ```

The date column is a string, which can be converted to Datetime with a data conversion component before being inserted into the database.
The Culture is set to US English, but this can be changed to your specific needs.  This hint will accept the local time format, i.e. MM/dd/yyyy.

TryParse() returns true if it can successfully parse a date from the input string.  When it returns false, we just set the column to null.