# Retain NULL not working for all columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a flat file with the following information which I am trying to load it into a SQL Server table with same columns and data type as date -

```
StartDate,EndDate
2017-01-02,2017-03-01

2017-01-02,2017-03-01
```

Note that second row is blank. Now I am setting both the source columns as `DT_DBDATE` data type. Also in the Flat File Source I am checking on the option `Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow`

At the destination DFT I am enabling the `Keep NULL` option.
Here is the problem. When I run the package I am seeing null for StartDate but for EndDate I see the following error -

> Error:Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

Any idea how to get over this or what is causing this problem?

[image: DataViewer output]

Comment: Dates in flat files are a huge pain to work with. I would recommend staging to an intermediate table as text, then and reformat when you insert into your real table. Probably save you the trouble. Doesn't show the cause of the problem but at least you have a quick workaround.

Comment: It's expecting two fields, but it's reading the blank line as one field (as there's no comma), so there's not even a NULL for EndDate, it's just missing.

Comment: @Donnie - Thanks for pointing that out, you are right the line doesn't have the needed delimiter. Let me give it a try having the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

The empty rows does not contains any column delimiter which mean it contains only one column, which will cause problems while reading from the falt file.

**How To Fix it**

In the flat file connection manager remove the column delimiter and read each row as one column of type `DT_STR` and set the length to `4000`

[image]

Then Add a script component and do the following:

1. Check if the row is empty

   - If yes output empty columns
   - If not split the row into columns
2. Output must contains the columns you needed

[image]

You can use a similar code: *(i used vb.net)*

```
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        If Not Row.Column0_IsNull AndAlso
                    Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0) Then

            Dim strcolumnms() As String = Row.Column0.Split(CChar(";"))

            Dim dtTemp As Date


            If DateTime.TryParse(strcolumnms(0), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtTemp) Then

                Row.Column1 = dtTemp

            Else

                Row.Column1_IsNull = True

            End If


            If DateTime.TryParse(strcolumnms(1), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtTemp) Then

                Row.Column2 = dtTemp

            Else

                Row.Column2_IsNull = True

            End If


        Else

            Row.Column1_IsNull = True
            Row.Column2_IsNull = True





        End If

    End Sub
```

## Dealing with dates in Flat files

It is better to choose `DT_STR` type when working with date values (or other data types) stored in a flat files and convert them (after checking if they are well formed) using a `Script Component` or `Data Conversion` Transformations.

**Using Script Component**

First you have to add a `Script component`, mark the date column as input, create a new output column of type `DT_DBDATE`

*If you want to check for specific dates formats you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method or you use [DateTime.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to try parsing date based on CultureInfo Date Formats.*

**I will give two examples:**
*Assuming that the input Column name is `inDate` and the output column is `outDate`*

*DateTime.TryParseExact()*

```
Dim strFormats() As String = {"yyyy-MM-dd"}

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)



    If Not Row.inDate_IsNull AndAlso
                 Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.inDate) Then


        Dim dtTemp As DateTime

        If DateTime.TryParseExact(Row.inDate, strFormats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtTemp) Then

            Row.outDate = dtTemp

        Else

            Row.outDate_IsNull = True

        End If



    End If
End Sub
```

*DateTime.TryParse()*

```
 Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)



    If Not Row.inDate_IsNull AndAlso
                 Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.inDate) Then


        Dim dtTemp As DateTime

        If DateTime.TryParse(Row.inDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtTemp) Then

            Row.outDate = dtTemp

        Else

            Row.outDate_IsNull = True

        End If



    End If
End Sub
```

you can read more about Datetime conversion using SSIS script component in this posts:

- [SSIS Source Format Implicit Conversion for Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035354/ssis-source-format-implicit-conversion-for-datetime/42038060#42038060)
- [SSIS convert string date with various formats to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441398/ssis-convert-string-date-with-various-formats-to-datetime)

**Using Data Conversion Transformation**

Use a Data Conversion Component to convert the `DT_STR` column to `DT_DBDATE` and on the `Error Output` set `Ignore failure` so values that cannot be converted is replaced by `NULL`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update and I completely agree dealing with dates in a flat file is extremely tiresome. Best to have it via Data Conversion or Derived Column and checking for blanks which is what I have done and I blogged about it here - vankadarakarthik.com. Donnie had pointed out a very pertinent point of not having the delimiter itself. I will once run and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the updated answer. Appreciate it.