# Convert DDMonYY and time to datetime column in SSIS package (Derived Column)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

I have the following data:

`12APR19 0644` and I want to combine/transform these in SSIS so they appear in my final destination as:

```
2019-04-12 06:44:00.00
```

I've tried using `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) [DateColumn] [TimeColumn]` but this gives me a generic error. Anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

First transform your string to dd mmm yyyy hh:mm then use the type case dt_date:

```
(DT_DATE)"12 APR 2019 06:44"
```

returns:

> 4/12/2019 6:44:00 AM

which you can further transform get the format you want.  OTOH if your destination is a SQL Server database, you can do:

```
(DT_WSTR, 20)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"12 APR 2019 06:44"
```

which yields

> 2019-04-12 06:44:00

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with a single `stuff()`

**Example**

```
Select AsDateTime = try_convert(datetime,stuff('12APR19 0644',11,0,':'))
```

**Returns**

```
AsDateTime
2019-04-12 06:44:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

### Derived Column solution

Assuming that the column name is `DateColumn`, you can use a derived column with the following expression:

```
"20" + SUBSTRING([DateColumn],6,2) + "-" + 
(SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "JAN" ? "01" :
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "FEB" ? "02" : 
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "MAR" ? "03" :
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "APR" ? "04" :
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "MAY" ? "05" : 
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "JUN" ? "06" :
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "JUL" ? "07" :
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "AUG" ? "08" :
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "SEP" ? "09" : 
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "OCT" ? "10" : 
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "NOV" ? "11" : 
SUBSTRING( [DateColumn],3,3) == "DEC"? "12":"")
  + "-" SUBSTRING([DateColumn],1,2) + " " +  SUBSTRING([DateColumn],9,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING([DateColumn],11,2) + "00.00"
```

*Input*

> 12APR19 0644

*Result*

> 2019-04-19 06:00:00.00

*Note that if the output column data type is date then you need to cast the expression above to `(DT_DATE)` or `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)`*

---

### Script Component solution

You can add a script component and use the following line of code to convert this column *(assuming that input column is `DateColumn` and output column is `OutDateColumn`)*

```
Row.OutDateColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.DateColumn,"ddMMMyy HH:mm",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If the output is a string column then use the following code:

```
Row.OutDateColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.DateColumn,"ddMMMyy HH:mm",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ff);;
```

---

### References

- [Convert month name to month number in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634701/convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-ssis)