# Why expression of Derived Column component don't working with empty value in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

Can someone advice me please?

[image]

I have table in SQL Server

```sql
create table t_test_date 
(
  tcol_date date, 
  tcol_varchar varchar(20), 
  tcol_date1 date
)
```

When I try insert data from flat file with content

```
COL_DATE
20-DEC-33
20-NOV-33
10-MAY-28
10-NOV-21

10-MAY-17
11-MAY-17
--(To Allow has empty values)
```

Expression value of Derived Column component is:

```
COL_DATE == "" || ISNULL(COL_DATE) ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : (DT_DBDATE)COL_DATE
```

I got error:

> [Derived Column [17]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[COL_DATE]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Answer (score 1):

The error cause is not the blank values, it is the date format. Since `DD-MMM-YY` format cannot be converted to `DT_DBDATE` data type.

Try converting the month name to month number and cahnge the date format. As example, the following expression convert `DD-MMM-YY` format to `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```
([COL_DATE] == "" || ISNULL([COL_DATE])) ? NULL(DT_DATE) :
(DT_DATE)("20" + RIGHT([COL_DATE],2) + "-" + 
(SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "JAN" ? "01" :
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "FEB" ? "02" : 
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "MAR" ? "03" :
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "APR" ? "04" :
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "MAY" ? "05" : 
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "JUN" ? "06" :
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "JUL" ? "07" :
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "AUG" ? "08" :
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "SEP" ? "09" : 
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "OCT" ? "10" : 
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "NOV" ? "11" : 
SUBSTRING( [COL_DATE],4,3) == "DEC"? "12": "00") 
+ "-" + LEFT([COL_DATE],2)  )
```

#### References

- [Convert month name to month number in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634701/convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-ssis/44638872#44638872)